What is the minimum distance $d$ of a polynomial in the polynomial quotient ring $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/\langle x^m+1\rangle$?
Suppose I have a polynomial ring $R = \mathbb{F}_2[x]/\langle x^m+1\rangle$, and a string of polynomials $r[x]\cdot(p[x], q[x])$, where $p,q$ are fixed polynomials. How to find (analytical lower bounds to) the minimum distance (or weight) of the string, given any $r[x]\in R$?
Example: suppose $m > 5$ and $(p[x],q[x]) = (1, 1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)$. Then, its weight is 1+5=6. However, we can multiply by any polynomial $r[x]$ to find $(r[x]p[x],r[x]q[x])$ with lower weight. Pick $r[x]=1+x$. Then, $(1+x, 1+x^5)$ has weight 4, lower than 6. Can we tell a priori how low this weight can go, even if it's a crude lower bound?
